# How to check if an internal URI exists using Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, uri, redirect

Using a Zend application I need to verify if an URI exists (internally to my application) before redirecting a user to that page. How can I perform this control?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zend Framework 2, this is very simple.

Let say we want to check if an URI matches against registered router and redirect the user if this is different from the current url.

```
$goto = 'http://www.mysite.tld/admin';

$request  = $this->getRequest();
$request->setUri($goto);

if ($routeToBeMatched = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Router')->match($request)) {
    $currentRouteMatchName = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
    if ($routeToBeMatched->getMatchedRouteName() != $currentRouteMatchName) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($goto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of doing this... see below.

I think best approach is using ACL MVC rules - adds security to your application and can be used for checking if resources (model/controller/action) exists.

**Option 1**

Build the class name and get it's method to see if your action exists. Either use [`get_class_methods`](https://www.php.net/get_class_methods) or [`ReflectionClass::getMethods`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php)

```
/**
 * @param string $controller name of controller e.g. "index"
 * @param string $action name of action e.g. "index", "myAction"
 * @param string $module (optional) name of the current module 
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _isControllerAction($controller, $action, $module = '')
{
    $module = ($module == 'default') ? '' : $module;
    $class = ucfirst($module) . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';
    $methods = get_class_methods($class);
    return in_array("{$action}Action", $methods);
}
```

**Option 2**

You can check if module/controller are dispatchable. This does not check the action and messes with request! If you go this way then add additional code to restore request state.

```
protected function isDispatchableController()
{
    $this->getRequest()
            ->setModuleName('default')
            ->setControllerName('index');

    $dispatcher = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getDispatcher();

    /* @var $dispatcher Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard */
    return $dispatcher->isDispatchable($this->getRequest());
}
```

**Option 3**

technically you can skip all this checking and implement default [`ErrorHandler`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler) and let it redirect to the ErrorController... then add special handling for 404

**Option 4**

if you are using ACL you can check if resource exists and user has access to it.
Here is good article on [Zend ACL MVC Integration](http://devzone.zend.com/1269/zend_acl-and-mvc-integration-part-ii-advanced-use/)